# Keil v.6 preprocessor defines

Tags: keil

Can someone please explain this screenshot to me?
`#if !defined __ARM_COMPILER_V6__ #eeror #endif` 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQris.png)
I'm getting this error
I do not get it Macro **ARM_COMPILER_6** has to be definrd
////////////
For Keil v.5 I had code which based upon what is defined #if defined  **GNUC** or __CC_ARM was printing via __io_putchar() for GCC of fputc() for ARMCC via ITM
Now I can't compile this file
Maybe someone has this tool for v.6 and ready to share?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Your 3-line code snippet apparently means that file requires the version 6 ARM compiler.  Do you have Keil v6?

Comment: Did you look at the given screenshot?

Comment: The screenshot shows the code.  It certainly doesn't show any errors.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: You should see that I have selected the default compiler v.6

Comment: It shoes that the ARM_COMPILER_6 is not defined even on the screenshot it is chosen as the default compiler to use.

Comment: Your screenshot certainly does NOT show that ARM_COMPILER_6 is not defined.  You don't show any compilation results at all.  All you show is an editor screen, and the editor is not a compiler.  The editor has underlined `#eeror` because that word is misspelled.

Comment: @Tom Roberts That is exactly why I did make this screenshot. On the same screen, one can see that the compiler sees  ARM_COMPILER_6 is not defined and at the same time the settings are showing that the compiler v6 is selected as default. So what the...nonsense?

Comment: No.  There is NOTHING in your screenshot that shows what the compiler thinks.  The left side shows three lines of code in the editor.  The right side shows part of a dialog box.  That's it.  No errors, no warnings, no compilation results.

Comment: @Tim Roberts On the dialog box you should see that the default compiler is version 6! How else can I prove that something is wrong with the automatic defines?

Comment: You haven't proven anything!  What makes you think there is an error?  I don't see an error anywhere.  There's NOTHING that shows me the symbol is not defined.  Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: There are two facts:
1. ARM_COMPILER_6 is not defined - preprocessor generates the requested error
2. The compilation was performed with the arm compiler v.6 
What else is not clear?

Comment: You never said that the compiler generated an error, nor does your screenshot show that.  That is a KEY piece of information for you to omit.

Comment: I have another snippet of code. 

`static int arm[3] = {
#if defined __ARMCC_VERSION
   __ARMCC_VERSION,
#else   
  0,
#endif
#if defined __ARMCOMPILER_VERSION
  __ARMCOMPILER_VERSION,
#else   
  0,
#endif
#if defined  __GNUC__  
  1,
#else 
0
#endif  
};`

**Immediately want to say that -there is NO option -gni. **
But why do I see that __GNUC__ is defined???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ARM documentation [here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101754/0616/armclang-Reference/Other-Compiler-specific-Features/Predefined-macros) the compiler version macro is  `__ARMCOMPILER_VERSION` or `__ARMCC_VERSION`

It is defined as decimal number in form Mmmuuxx where M is 5 or 6.

Where have you found `__ARM_COMPILER_V6__`?

Comment: https://community.arm.com/support-forums/f/keil-forum/53488/preprocessor-define-when-migrating-code-from-compiler-version-5-to-6
But it was my mistake, I did not pay enough attention. Sorry